# How do I configure a repo so I can install dependencies easily?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, update-manager

I want to install Vagrant.  When I try to install Vagrant (with dpkg -i command), I get errors like these:

```
 Package ruby-bundler is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-childprocess (>= 0.3.7); however:
  Package ruby-childprocess is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-erubis (>= 2.7.0); however:
  Package ruby-erubis is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-i18n (>= 0.6.0); however:
  Package ruby-i18n is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-listen; however:
  Package ruby-listen is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-log4r (>= 1.1.9); however:
  Package ruby-log4r is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-nokogiri; however:
  Package ruby-nokogiri is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-rb-inotify; however:
  Package ruby-rb-inotify is not installed.
 vagrant depends on ruby-rest-client; however:
  Package ruby-rest-client is not installed.
```

When I try to install those individual dependencies above with apt-get commands, I see errors like these:

> E: Package 'ruby-rest-client' has no installation candidate

Is there a repository that I can configure to be able to install these ruby dependencies?  My /etc/apt/sources.list file shows these entries:

```
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
deb http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
deb-src http:// us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main
```

(There are no spaces after the http constructors. I put spaces there b/c I cannot post links.)

Is there a URL for a free repo that I can just add?

Comment: Try using apt instead of dpkg. apt handles dependencies.

Comment: I tried "apt-get install ruby-nokogiri" but I got this 'E: Package 'ruby-nokogiri' has no installation candidate.'  I tried 'apt-get install vagrant' but I got 'E: Unable to locate package vagrant.'

Comment: Where did you download the package? If it has dependencies which are not in the official repositories, a competent package provider should explain how to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **main** enabled, you need to add **unvierse** repos, as it's not a core maintained package, a search of ubuntu packages shows which repo packages come from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ruby-rest-client

Add the following lines to you apt sources.list, then apt-get update:

```
# Universe Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

###### Ubuntu Update Repos Universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
```